# I can't get my button to center in my div

Tags: html, css, button

I know it's been asked dozen of times, but I'm stuck in my code and I don't understand why my code is not responding.

I would like to center my button in a responsive way : it must center under 768px and have another reaction above. To get it in line is not a problem, but impossible to center it when the screen shrinks.

Here's my code :

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #callout {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  #calloutButton {
    text-align: center !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="m-portlet m-portlet--mobile m-portlet--body-progress-">
  <div class="card card-custom gutter-b bg-diagonal bg-diagonal-light-primary">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div id="callout" class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between p-4 flex-xl-nowrap">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column mr-5 font_18">
          <a class="text-hover-primary mb-5" style="color: #002577">
            <strong>Accédez à la simulation complète</strong>
          </a>
          <p class="text-dark" align="justify">
            Pour préparer votre rendez-vous et confirmer le prêt étudiant bancaire
          </p>
        </div>
        <div id="calloutButton" class="ml-6 ml-lg-0 ml-xxl-6 flex-shrink-0 justify-content-center">
          <a href="{{ route('contrib_file', ['contributor_id'=>$contributor->id]) }}" class="btn font-weight-bolder text-uppercase btn-primary py-4 px-6">
            <img alt="download pdf" src='{{ asset("assets/images/pdf.png") }}' />&nbsp&nbsp
            <strong>Simulation</strong>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Where's my mistake ? what's the trick to obtain a nice button in the center of my card ? I'm quite new in the job, so sorry if it's a dummy question.

Thanks for your help

Comment: what isnt working for you? in the code you provided it works perfectly for me.

Comment: same, I do not see what is wrong

Comment: You should use class instead of id for giving the styles, and for your issue you can add margin:0 auto ;  this will always keep your div in  center

Comment: Hi, I think your snippet needs some library/CSS file adding (bootstrap?) otherwise we are just looking at your text-align center not at the full environment.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, I added margin:0 auto and it worked at perfection.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried

```
.yourdiv{
  float: center;
  width: 100vw;
  text-align: center;
 }
```

Comment: There's no such thing as `float: center;`